# style PHP error message

Tags: php, html, css, styling

I want to style my error messages on this PHP output. The code I am using is below.

```
<?php  
if (empty($errors) === false){
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach($errors as $error){
        echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

and my CSS that I tried using:

```
#error_message {
list-style:none;
color:#F00; 
}
```

I have tried putting an id on the UL and Li, they don't do anything. I have also tried having a span around all the PHP code.

Comment: *they don't do anything* ?? What is your expected output ? Have you styled css after giving ul & li an id ?

Comment: What do you mean "no stupid comments"? How is someone telling you to actually try to do research, instead of asking others for help a "stupid comment?"

Comment: @Rikesh my expected output is a red font and no bullets. And yes, i have an external CSS attached with the id.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I once asked a question on here and got a reply to google it, which I had done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id's must be unique throughout the form. Only give an id to the ul `<ul id="myUL">` and use css like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #myUL {
    style_att: style_att_val;
  }

  #myUL li {
    style_att: style_att_val;
  }
</style>
```

or put it in a css file and link to it.